# Natural Language searching - solr

Tags: php, search, solr

I am trying to search for a product with a filter in the following format using solr search

> samsung phone below 10000

The name and price are separate fields. The **expected result** is that all Samsung mobiles below 10000 rupees price are shown.

But now the search result is based on the name field only . Can this search be performed considering all the fields with a single query?

My query :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/myproducts/select?indent=on&q=memory card below 1000&rows=100&wt=json
```

My data-config.xml is :

```
     <entity name="master_products"  
    pk="id"
    query="select p.* ,b.* ,c.* from master_products p ,master_brands b,master_product_categories c  where b.id=p.brand_id and c.id=p.product_category_id"
    deltaImportQuery="SELECT * FROM master_products WHERE product_name='${dataimporter.delta.product_name}' "
    >
    <!-- or b.brnad='${dataimporter.delta.brand}' -->

     <field column="product_name" name="name"/> 
     <field column="product_description" name="description"/> 
     <field column="id" name="id"/>
     <field column="mrp" name="mrp"/> 
     <field column="brand_id" name="brandID"/>


  <entity name="master_brands" 
    query="select * from master_brands"
    deltaImportQuery="select * from master_brands where id ={master_products.brand_id}" processor="SqlEntityProcessor" cacheImpl="SortedMapBackedCache" >
    <field column="brand" name="brand" />
  </entity>

  <entity name="master_product_categories" 
    query="select * from master_product_categories"
    deltaImportQuery="select * from master_product_categories where id ={master_products.   product_category_id}" processor="SqlEntityProcessor" cacheImpl="SortedMapBackedCache" >
    <field column="category" name="category" />
  </entity>

 </entity>
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include your query?

Comment: my query is : http://localhost:8983/solr/myproducts/select?indent=on&q=memory%20card%20below%201000&rows=100&wt=json

Comment: that's your localhost!

Answer (score 0):

There are few different ways to achieve what you're asking. If you want to keep it simple and don't have restrictions on the query parser, then you can use the eDismax query parser in the following way:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/myproducts/select?indent=on&q=memory card below 1000&defType=edismax&qf=name description&rows=100&wt=json
```

Where QF:

> The qf (Query Fields) Parameter
>
> The qf parameter introduces a list of fields, each of which is
>   assigned a boost factor to increase or decrease that particular
>   field's importance in the query. For example, the query below:
>
> qf="fieldOne^2.3 fieldTwo fieldThree^0.4"
>
> assigns fieldOne a boost of 2.3, leaves fieldTwo with the default
>   boost (because no boost factor is specified), and fieldThree a boost
>   of 0.4. These boost factors make matches in fieldOne much more
>   significant than matches in fieldTwo, which in turn are much more
>   significant than matches in fieldThree.

From your question is not clear if you need also to filter results below 1000, in case you need it let me know and I will edit the answer adding the relevant filter to the query.